# VB.Net SQL issues

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I've been receiving errors with the following code below saying that the index is incorrect. I'm assuming this is an error with the SQL statement but I'm unsure what's wrong.

```
        Private Sub btnStock_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStock.Click
    frmStock.Visible = True
    Dim SQLCmd As String
    SQLCmd = "SELECT PartID,PartName,PartStockLevel,MakeName,ModelName FROM tblParts WHERE PartStockLevel <= StockWarnLevel;"
    RunSQLCmd("dt", SQLCmd)
    Dim inc As Integer = 0
    Dim NoLowStock As Boolean
    If DataTable IsNot Nothing AndAlso DataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        frmStock.txtPartID.Text = DataTable.Rows(inc).Item(0)
        frmStock.txtName.Text = DataTable.Rows(inc).Item(1)
        frmStock.NUDStockLvl.Value = DataTable.Rows(inc).Item(2)
        frmStock.txtMake.Text = DataTable.Rows(inc).Item(3)
        frmStock.txtModel.Text = DataTable.Rows(inc).Item(4)
    Else
        frmStock.lblLowStock.Visible = True
        frmStock.btnFirstRecord.Visible = False
        frmStock.btnIncDown.Visible = False
        frmStock.btnIncUp.Visible = False
        frmStock.btnLastRecord.Visible = False
        NoLowStock = True
    End If
    If NoLowStock = False Then
        frmStock.Panel1.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

    Public Sub RunSQLCmd(ByVal DTorDS As String, ByRef SQLCmd As String)
    DataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLCmd, con)
    ConnectDB()
    Try
        If DTorDS = "dt" Then
            DataTable = New DataTable
            DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)
        Else
            DataSet = New DataSet
            DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, "srcDataSet")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        con.Close()
    End Try
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the exact error message? I am not aware of any error like that in VB or SQL that should result from a SELECT statement, or from reading it's resulting rows or columns.  Nor am I aware of an ADO.net routine named "RunSQLCmd"?

Comment: Can you show the code of RunSQLCmd? The only reasons, to not have a return from `WHERE PartStockLevel <= StockWarnLevel` are 1) You don't have any record with PartStockLevel less than StockWarnLevel or 2) Something is wrong in RunSQLCmd. Let me add also that it is a very bad programming practice to use exception to control your code flow.

Comment: I've removed the exception and changed it using the techniques suggested by Brentkeller below. Is it possible in SQL to compare two fields directly as in the command above? The idea is that it returns certain fields when the stock level goes below a 'warning' level. I don't think that RunSQLCmd is the problem as I've used it elsewhere in my solution and it's working fine, but I have included the code above just in case. I'm sorry for my beginner ways of programming but experiences like this can only help me in the long run! [Here](http://bit.ly/HqPnAe) is the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error probably comes from you looking at a row index that doesn't exist in the results. You should check that the table has rows before trying to get the data.

Something like this:
If DataTable IsNot Nothing AndAlso DataTable.Rows.Count >0 Then
... Code here...
End If

Comment: Yes - the error is due to the SQL statement not returning any results - any idea as to what's wrong? There is data that should be returned but I'm not sure why it's not being returned?

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple way

```
dim dt as new datatable

using connection as new sqlconnection("server=SERVER;database=DATABASE;uid=USERID;pwd=PASSWORD")
connection.open()
     using cmd as new sqlcommand("SELECT PartID,PartName,PartStockLevel,MakeName,ModelName FROM tblParts WHERE PartStockLevel <= StockWarnLevel", connection)
     dt.load(cmd.executereader)
     end using
end using
```